# proxychains unable to connect

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-20.04

Here is the terminal log when I run

```
proxychains4 chromium google.com
```

```
[proxychains] config file found: /etc/proxychains4.conf
[proxychains] preloading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxychains.so.4
[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14
2020/12/03 10:49:55.184436 system_key.go:147: cannot determine seccomp compiler version in generateSystemKey: invalid format of version-info: "[proxychains] DLL init: proxychains-ng 4.14\ne8aa8f6eafa3be3b3303d3ba093fddcefa875298 2.4.3 9b218ef9a4e508dd8a7f848095cb8875d10a4bf28428ad81fdc3f8dac89108f7 bpf-actlog"
Gtk-Message: 10:49:55.431: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 10:49:55.432: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
[8647:8647:1203/104955.493174:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
```

And also, my IP address remains same...
Any ways to fix?